How to use piecewise/partial .diff() or .pct_change() on rows?
I have an issue of performing .diff() and .pct_change() calls on rows. The original table has 51 countries so I will use an example of three countries here as follows:
import pandas as pd
data = {'country' : ['Andorra', 'Andorra', 'Andorra', 'Andorra',
                     'Italy', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'Italy',
                     'Slovakia', 'Slovakia', 'Slovakia', 'Slovakia'],
        'year': [1987, 1988, 1989, 1990,
                 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990,
                 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990],
        'population': [10, 12, 17, 21, 
                       34, 27, 22, 26,
                       18, 23, 45, 12]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

which results in the following dataframe df




country
year
population




0
Andorra
1987
10


1
Andorra
1988
12


2
Andorra
1989
17


3
Andorra
1990
21


4
Italy
1987
34


5
Italy
1988
27


6
Italy
1989
22


7
Italy
1990
26


8
Slovakia
1987
18


9
Slovakia
1988
23


10
Slovakia
1989
45


11
Slovakia
1990
12



If applying df.population.diff() directly, I get the following result:




country
year
population
change




0
Andorra
1987
10
NaN


1
Andorra
1988
12
2.0


2
Andorra
1989
17
5.0


3
Andorra
1990
21
4.0


4
Italy
1987
34
13.0


5
Italy
1988
27
-7.0


6
Italy
1989
22
-5.0


7
Italy
1990
26
4.0


8
Slovakia
1987
18
-8.0


9
Slovakia
1988
23
5.0


10
Slovakia
1989
45
22.0


11
Slovakia
1990
12
-33.0



which is wrong, of course, because the change for Italy, 1987 was calculated by subtraction from Andorra, 1990. I must generate a df.change column in which every entry for individual country, 1987 will be NaN.
In this simple example, I was able to get such a dataframe by using .diff() "semi-manually" by writing the following code:
diff_andorra  =  df[ df.country== "Andorra" ].population.diff()
diff_italy    =  df[ df.country== "Italy" ].population.diff()
diff_slovakia =  df[ df.country== "Slovakia" ].population.diff()

diff_series = pd.concat([diff_andorra, diff_italy, diff_slovakia])

df['change'] = diff_series

This resulted in the desired dataframe:




country
year
population
change




0
Andorra
1987
10
NaN


1
Andorra
1988
12
2.0


2
Andorra
1989
17
5.0


3
Andorra
1990
21
4.0


4
Italy
1987
34
NaN


5
Italy
1988
27
-7.0


6
Italy
1989
22
-5.0


7
Italy
1990
26
4.0


8
Slovakia
1987
18
NaN


9
Slovakia
1988
23
5.0


10
Slovakia
1989
45
22.0


11
Slovakia
1990
12
-33.0



But since the original dataframe has 51 countries altogether, I can't apply the "semi-manual" technique on all of them. My idea was to create a for loop of the following form:
diff_temp = pd.Series(dtype=float)
for individual_country in set(df.country):
    temp = df[ df.country== individual_country ].population.diff()
    diff_temp = pd.concat(temp)

The first line defines an empty series for float datatype (in analogy how we often create empty list() or dict() objects). The set(df.country) contains the name of all the country entries, but they appear only once, due to the nature of set() type. For country in the set, the temp variable holds the .diff() series which would then be .concat()-ed or .append()-ed to the diff_temp series.
And it is on this last line that my code breaks down, showing the following error:
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "Series"
If I only print(temp) after each loop, the output shows this:
0    NaN
1    2.0
2    5.0
3    4.0
Name: population, dtype: float64
4    NaN
5   -7.0
6   -5.0
7    4.0
Name: population, dtype: float64
8      NaN
9      5.0
10    22.0
11   -33.0
Name: population, dtype: float64

This indicates that "piecewise" .diff()-ing is doable, but I have problem merging them into one series which would then be added as another column with df['change'] = diff_temp, in order to achieve the above mentioned table, i.e. this (repeated for easier reference):




country
year
population
change




0
Andorra
1987
10
NaN


1
Andorra
1988
12
2.0


2
Andorra
1989
17
5.0


3
Andorra
1990
21
4.0


4
Italy
1987
34
NaN


5
Italy
1988
27
-7.0


6
Italy
1989
22
-5.0


7
Italy
1990
26
4.0


8
Slovakia
1987
18
NaN


9
Slovakia
1988
23
5.0


10
Slovakia
1989
45
22.0


11
Slovakia
1990
12
-33.0



I am uncertain what am I doing wrong. I tried using .append() but it resulted in df.change entries all being equal to NaN.

Pandas already knows how to handle groups, use groupby.diff:
df['change'] = df.groupby('country')['population'].diff()

A fix of your (less efficient) approach would have been to assign back without intermediate:
for individual_country in set(df.country):
    m = df.country == individual_country
    df.loc[m, 'change'] = df[m].population.diff()

Or to collect in a list:
tmp = []
for individual_country in set(df.country):
    tmp.append(df[df.country==individual_country].population.diff())
df['change'] = pd.concat(tmp)

Output:
     country  year  population  change
0    Andorra  1987          10     NaN
1    Andorra  1988          12     2.0
2    Andorra  1989          17     5.0
3    Andorra  1990          21     4.0
4      Italy  1987          34     NaN
5      Italy  1988          27    -7.0
6      Italy  1989          22    -5.0
7      Italy  1990          26     4.0
8   Slovakia  1987          18     NaN
9   Slovakia  1988          23     5.0
10  Slovakia  1989          45    22.0
11  Slovakia  1990          12   -33.0

for fun
If your data is sorted by country, then year, you could avoid the groupby using:
df = df.sort_values(by=['country', 'year'])

df['change'] = (df['population'].diff()
                .mask(df['country'].ne(df['country'].shift()))
               )


Ah, I felt it could be solved in one line of code, I just did not understand how. Most elegant :D Thank you for the proposal and offering few alternatives. It is a fun learn how each works.

Using groupby
You can very easily achieve what you're after using pandas groupby.
First I would sort the dataframe by the year column, just in case your data isn't already in chronological order, using df.sort_values() like this:
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='year')

Which will make the dataframe look like the below. (Note that now the countries are all jumbled up, which is fine for passing into the groupby,  but if it makes you feel more comfortable/understand better, you could order by both country and year using df.sort_values(by=['country', 'year']):
    country  year   population
0   Andorra  1987   10
4   Italy    1987   34
8   Slovakia 1987   18
1   Andorra  1988   12
5   Italy    1988   27
...

Then you can add the .groupby() onto this.  Pass the column name of 'country' into the groupby to specify that this is the values you want to group onto. Then specify that the data in the 'population' column is what you'd like to use, and finally specify that that function you would like to use is .diff(), like this:
df_sorted.groupby('country')['population'].diff()

Which will return the new 'change' column you're after:
    population
0   
1   2.0
2   5.0
3   4.0
4   
5   -7.0
6   -5.0
7   4.0
8   
9   5.0
10  22.0
11  -33.0

You then just need to assign this to the new 'change' column in your dataframe (it should be noted that if the data isn't in chronological order, you'll need to assign the new column to the sorted dataframe).
All this can be done in one line of code like this:
 df['change'] = (df.sort_values(by='year')
                 .groupby('country')['population'].diff())

Groupby is doing the same thing you're trying to do with your for loop, but it's much neater and more efficient (which will really show when trying to do something like this on a large dataset).
Fixing your code
In terms of fixing your code, your last line doesn't work as pd.concat(temp) doesn't specify a second series (diff_temp) to concatenate onto.  Changing this line to the below works:
diff_temp = pd.concat([diff_temp, temp])

However, I strongly recommend using the groupby method that already exists, no point re-inventing the wheel :)

Sorting by country is not needed since you're going to groupby afterwards ;)

I know, but would produce a neater dataframe in the intermediate step, which my brain liked :p

If you sort by both you could however use a groupby-less approach (I'll demonstrate as update)

I tend to use .groupby() when I want need to .sum() the data (or some other function of similar grouping nature). Since I am going here piece by piece (calculating the differences) in given intervals and I do not feel yet skillful enough, I thought the initial approach would be easier for me to follow. I have no doubt .groupby() is a powerful tool, but at this beginner stage I kinda feel more comfortable using something alike in my initial proposal. It is easier for me to "see" the code dynamics.But that's a nice thing about programming - more paths to same solution. In any case, thanks

@Demenaio using .diff() in a .groupby() works the same way as using .sum(), so not that big of a step.  It's a tidier piece of code and much more efficient than doing it piece by piece.  If you really want to stick with your approach,  then use @mozways list suggestion, as growing a series in a for loop is frowned upon and even more inefficient.  I will break down my answer a bit more so hopefully you can understand the groupby better :)

Yes, I get it. Less lines of code -> better code. It will come with time, experience and lots of tracebacks :D

@Demenaio it's not necessarily that less lines is always better, in this is case it's also that using groupby is more efficient (i.e. takes less time and uses less computing power).  In some cases, it is possible for a more efficient piece of code to be longer in the number of lines.  Both are important things to consider when coding
